# Recording Spectral Lines at Home

Tags: telescope, spectroscopy, spectra

I was wondering if it would be possible to record the emission/absorption spectra of stars without expensive spectroscopy equipment. Would it be possible to somehow utilize diffraction grating? I own a Newtonian with a 130mm aperture if that helps.

Comment: some related links: [Has anyone seen an actual spectrum of a satellite made by an amateur photographer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21876/12102)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a link to a [diffraction grating](https://www.rspec-astro.com/star-analyser/) that can do what you want. It is mounted in a 1.25" filter ring that attaches to an eyepiece, or to most astro cameras. I believe they also sell adapters for other cameras and software to extract spectra from the photos.

Here is a link to a spectra of [Vega](https://gvk.smugmug.com/Astrophotography/Spectroscopy/i-jk4zSHs/A) that I took with a 120 mm refractor using  the Star Analyser grating.

Comment: Cool!  The OP should keep in mind that the spectral range may be limited by the glass and the IR filter in his camera.